the discord bot, which records information in the embed
I wanted to write a bot that adds a value to embed with the /add command to get a sheet with values, if the /del command then it removes 1 value from embed and if I call the /list command Then embed is output with values in a column, please help.
require('dotenv').config();
const {Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionsBitField, Permission } = require ("discord.js")
const client = new Client ({intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

client.on(Events.ClientReady, (x) => {
    console.log(`${x.user.tag} is ready!`);
    client.user.setActivity(`Coding Discord Bot for reply`);

     const add = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
        subcommand
          .setName("add")
          .setDescription("Adds points to the user.")
      )
    .addNumberOption(option =>
        option
        .setName ("id 2")
        .setDescription ("second value")
        .setRequired(true)
    )

    const del = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName ("del")
    .setDescription ("delete stroke")

    const embed = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName ("embed")
    .setDescription ("embed")

client.application.commands.create(add);
client.application.commands.create(del);
client.application.commands.create(embed);

});

client.on("interactionCreate", (interaction) => {


        if (interaction.commandName === "embed") {
            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setAuthor({
              name: "Info",
              url: "https://example.com",
            })
            .setTitle("Example Title")
            .setURL("https://example.com")
            .setImage("https://cubedhuang.com/images/alex-knight-unsplash.webp")
            .setThumbnail("https://dan.onl/images/emptysong.jpg")
            .setColor("#00b0f4")
            .setFooter({
              text: "Example Footer",
              iconURL: "https://slate.dan.onl/slate.png",
            })
            .setTimestamp();

            interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]});
    }

});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);

